# pd.pivot_table when columns are the dates

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a table that I  want to pivot

[image]

but the dates are in columns and I'm not sure how I can pivot all columns, after that I can pd.to_datetime and sort it.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Country Name','Country Code'], value_name='year', var_name='val')
print (df.head())
  Country Name Country Code   val       year
0    Argentina          ARG  1961  20.310698
1       Brazil          BRA  1961  31.302529
2        Chile          CHL  1961   6.568982
3        China          CHN  1961  15.253994
4     Colombia          COL  1961   8.082284
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['Country Name','Country Code'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='val')
        .rename(columns={'level_2':'year'}))
print (df.head())
  Country Name Country Code  year        val
0    Argentina          ARG  1961  20.310698
1    Argentina          ARG  1962  28.871842
2    Argentina          ARG  1963  25.591154
3    Argentina          ARG  1964  28.774617
4    Argentina          ARG  1965  21.232935
```